unity video player webgl
I have a problem. I use the videoplayer component to display videos with audio. But when the video is played again, after the first show, it starts to blunt hard. Everything is shown very slowly, almost 3-5 frames per second. I don't know what this is about, please help me!
It is necessary that when you replay the video, it should be the same as the first time
